# How can the datatype of a JSON property be determined?

Tags: java, json

In Java, I know you can check if a key is present with the isNull() method. Is there a way to check what kind of data the key holds?

Consider the following examples.

I would want a function like JSONBody.getDataType("key") and it would return String

```
{
    "key" : "value"
}
```

I would want a function like JSONBody.getDataType("key") and it would return JSONObject

```
{
    "key" : { 
        "parm1" : "value1",
        "parm2" : "value2"
    }
}
```

I would want a function like JSONBody.getDataType("key") and it would return JSONArray

```
{
    "key" : [
        "value1",
        "value2",
        "value3"
    ]
}
```

I would want a function like JSONBody.getDataType("key") and it would return Boolean

```
{
    "key" : true
}
```

Does something like this exist?

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9844494/json-to-java-objects-best-practice-for-modeling-the-json-stream .... there is no xsd ;)

Comment: Your array example is (incorrectly) defining a JSON object, not an array; need to switch the curly braces for square brackets.

Comment: You can do an IF else, and use instance of or equals. Checkout this thread:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/106336/how-do-i-find-out-what-type-each-object-is-in-a-arraylistobject

Comment: Parse it into a Map, retrieve the item as an Object, and test its class.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
JSONObject stuff = new JSONObject(whatever);
Object thing = stuff.get("key");
String classNameOfThing = thing.getClass().getName();
Systen.out.println("thing is a " + classNameOfThing);
if (thing instanceof Integer) {
    System.out.println("thing is an Integer");
}
```